# While clicking next link in a table region for an oaf page is not fectching the next set of rows?

Tags: oracle, oracleapplications

My oaf page has a table region, the next link in the table region to fetch the next 10 rows is not working however this same code while I deployed it in our local server was working fine.

Only in this new server I'm facing this problem all other features in the page are working fine.

I have imported the page using xml importer.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your datasource; Make sure the query that brings your result has more than 10 rows. This could explain why you cannot use this next page button.
- Maybe check server logs?
- Maybe enable Javascript for that new site on your IE?

Otherwise, you give so few information about your issue that it's difficult to help.

Let us know if you discover what's wrong.

Comment: The query brings all the records in the vo but i have limited it to 10 in a page for that region .When i click on the next 10 it is displaying the same result again this problem is in the new server where i have installed the code .In my dev and test instance i  did not face this issue.Thank you for the reply.